# Is there a way to create a data frame with rows for combinations of variables in other data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several data frames containing one column each. I want to create a data frame which has rows for each possible combination of the values in the other data frames.

I tried a workaround with nested for loops for each data frame but since i have about 20 data frames it became tedious quite fast.

```
# the data frames I already have
df1 <- data.frame(c("A","B","C")) 
colnames(df1) <- c("x")
df2 <- data.frame(c("ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE")) 
colnames(df2) <- c("y")

# the data frame I want to create
df3 <- data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  c("ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE", "ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE", "ALPHA","BRAVO","CHARLIE"))
colnames(df3) <- c("x", "y")
```

Comment: For completeness: `data.table::CJ`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `tidyr::crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(df1, df2)

#  df1$x df2$y  
#  <fct> <fct>  
#1 A     ALPHA  
#2 A     BRAVO  
#3 A     CHARLIE
#4 B     ALPHA  
#5 B     BRAVO  
#6 B     CHARLIE
#7 C     ALPHA  
#8 C     BRAVO  
#9 C     CHARLIE
```

You can just add all the dataframes in it and it would give you output for all combinations of it.

---

In base R, you could also use `merge` in `Reduce` by putting all the dataframes in one list.

```
Reduce(merge, list(df1, df2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(x= df1$x, y = df2$y)
#  x       y
#1: A   ALPHA
#2: A   BRAVO
#3: A CHARLIE
#4: B   ALPHA
#5: B   BRAVO
#6: B CHARLIE
#7: C   ALPHA
#8: C   BRAVO
#9: C CHARLIE
```